# Read the data from file and Sort the data using c#

Tags: c#

I need to read the 2D array from a text file and sort the column in ascending order.

My current implementation is:

1) Reading the data from file & split the values based on blank space
2) And assigning 3 column values to 3 Arraylists

I tried sorting each Arraylist with Sort() method. But could not get the required output, its only sorting the positive values & not negative values.

Code sample,

```
        ArrayList col1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList col2 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList col3 = new ArrayList();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"E:\ArrayCol1.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] split = Regex.Split(line, "[ \t]");

                if (split.Count() == 3)
                {
                    col1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(split[0]));
                    col2.Add(Convert.ToInt32(split[1]));
                    col3.Add(Convert.ToInt32(split[2]));
                }
            }
        }
        col1.Sort();
        foreach (int s in col1)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Textfile Data Array[4,3]:-

> 50   10    77
>
> -15  -215  -1
>
> -20  -600  -200
>
> 10   -70   1000

expected output,

> 50   10   1000
>
> 10   -70   77
>
> -15  -215  -1
>
> -20  -600  -200

Comment: Please show us what code you have implemented!  @Rao

Comment: Why are you using ArrayLists?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug?

`Sort()` does sort in ascending order. I had to use `OrderByDescending()` to make it descending.

Re-wrote your code:

```
List<int> col1 = new List<int>();
    List<int> col2 = new List<int>();
    List<int> col3 = new List<int>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\users\susingh\desktop\data.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while (true)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line==null)
            {
                break;
            }
            var numArray = line.Split('\t');
            col1.Add(Int32.Parse(numArray[0]));
            col2.Add(Int32.Parse(numArray[1]));
            col3.Add(Int32.Parse(numArray[2]));
        }
    }

    var Foo = col1.OrderByDescending(x=>x);
    foreach (var element in Foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList col1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList col2 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList col3 = new ArrayList();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Sample.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] split = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+");

        if (split.Count() == 3)
        {
            col1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(split[0]));
            col2.Add(Convert.ToInt32(split[1]));
            col3.Add(Convert.ToInt32(split[2]));
        }
    }
}

// sort all columns
col1.Sort();
col2.Sort();
col3.Sort();

// output is largest to smallest so invert sort
for (int i = col1.Count -1 ; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", col1[i], col2[i], col3[i]));
}
```